# Syncano User Management Profile Update Error

Tags: javascript, user-management, syncano

I tried to implement a user sign up for my app using the Syncano User Management system. I was able to successfully create a new user using the following JS Library code:

```
var sync = new Syncano({ apiKey: 'API_KEY', instance: 'INSTANCE' });
sync.user().add(signUp).then(function(res){
  console.log(res);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Then I tried to add profile fields to my user by following the code found here: https://www.syncano.io/user-management-for-your-apps/#adding-fields

```
var sync = new Syncano({ apiKey: 'API_KEY', instance: 'INSTANCE' });
sync.user().add(signUp).then(function(res){
  var instance = new Syncano({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    instance: INSTANCE_NAME,
    userKey: res.user_key
  });
  instance.class('user_profile').dataobject(res.id).update({firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last'});
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

When I make the second API call inside the .then() statement of the first, I get this error:

> "api.syncano.io/v1/instances/INSTANCE/classes/user_profile/objects/26/:1
>   PATCH
>   https://api.syncano.io/v1/instances/INSTANCE/classes/user_profile/objects/26/
>   404 (NOT FOUND) user.service.js:77 Error: {"detail":"Not found"}"

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking into this one. I'm not getting a 404, but I do get a different error. I may need to redo my examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with the sample code (that sadly I wrote).

The object that is returned after user creation has an `id` field for the `user` object, and a `profile.id` to modify the `user_profile` object.

The line needs to be this instead

```
instance.class('user_profile').dataobject(res.profile.id).update({firstName: 'First', lastName: 'Last'});
```

There is another caveat in the current system that I will also make a note of - you must first set the `other permissions` to `read` on the `user_profile` class.

This will eventually be changed in the platform to default to `read`.

Hope this helps!